# Symfony 2.7 framework.session.use_strict_mode

Tags: symfony, session

I have tried to set up use_strict_mode for sessions but I get the following error

> Unrecognized option "use_strict_mode" under "framework.session"

What is strange is that in the documentation for symfony 2.7 this option appears under framework.session, but at the end of the file in the full configuration reference it does not.

https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/configuration/framework.html#use-strict-mode

https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/configuration/framework.html#full-default-configuration

Is it maybe because this option was introduced in another version, 2.8 , 3.0 maybe? And there is a mistake in the docs?

Comment: At the very least, I can confirm that the option is indeed present in symfony `2.7` and more precisely `@2.7.3`, since that's the last stable version returned when executing `symfony new project 2.7`. So, the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: My installed version is 2.7.17-DEV...were could I look for the problem? My php version is 5.6.31, could it be that I need a special php extension for this?

Comment: I highly doubt it, since the framework itself is responsible for parsing the configuration, you are just providing values for specific options. I will look into it a little bit later.

Comment: Hello @Artamiel, do you have any updates on this subject? Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Stev, sorry for the late reply. There was no problem either to define this property with version `@2.7.17` as you mentioned.